# If power series converges to 0 $\forall$ $x \in (-R,R)$, then $a_n$ is $0$ for all $n$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

> Suppose that $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}x^{n}$$
>   converges for $x \in (-R,R)$.
>   Show that if $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in (-R,R)$ then $a_n=0$ for all $n$.

When I look at this , my guess is that the answer involves showing that the radius of convergence is infinity?
i.e showing $R=\infty$. Is this a correct approach?

Comment: Hint : what formula do you know relating the derivative of $f$ and coefficient $a_n$ ? What implies that $f \equiv 0$ on the open set (-R,R) for its derivatives ? (in other words, what can you say about unicity of such a developpement in power serie)

Comment: so, if we differentiate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}x^{n}$ we get $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_{n}x^{n-1}$ and as $x=0$ for $x \in (-R,R)$ then it is constant and so the derivative is constant for that interval... am I along the right line>

Comment: Yes, it is even simpler : taking your first derivative at zero should give you a link between $a_1$ and $f'$. Then differentiate $f'$ again and take the value at zero, and so on...then plug the fact that all derivatives and $f$ are null, it should do the trick

Comment: You introduce $f$ without saying anything. Presumably it is related to your power series?

Comment: Also presumably $R\neq0$?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that for some $N\geqslant 1$, we have $a_1=\dots=a_{N-1}=0$ and $a_N\neq 0$. Then write 
$$|a_Nx^N|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^Na_kx^k\right|\leqslant \left|\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty a_kx^k\right|,$$
which gives 
$$\tag{$\star$}|a_Nx^N|=|x^{N+1}|\left|\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{N+1+k}\cdot x^k\right|.$$
Using the fact that the series $\sum_n a_nx^n$ converges on $(-R,R)$, we can show that the function $x\mapsto \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{N+1+k}\cdot x^k$ is bounded on a neighborhood of $0$. Using $(\star)$ for $x\neq 0$, then letting $x\to 0$, we get a contradiction.